# woocommerce rest api and other plugins

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I am working with the woocommerce rest api which I can obtain data from fine. However I am also using a thirdparty plugin that allows the customer to select a pickup time at the checkout page.

Is there anyway I can pull the data from this plugin via the woocommrece rest api?

I am building an application to display the orders on another site, but not sure how I can capture this other data.